# Can I use OOP in Redux Store actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, redux, react-redux

I'm using React JS and Redux JS.
I know that Redux actions functions should be a pure function

But, I was reading about Object Oriented Programming (OOP) and its benefits.

So, Can I use OOP in Redux action (Class) instead of pure functions ??

For example:
If I've a state named "articles", It may have actions like:

```
function getArtcles() { ... }
function addArtcle({data}) { ... }
function deleteArtcle(id) { ... }
......
```

So, can I replce that with:

```
 class Artice {
    getArtcles() {...}
    addArtcle() {...}
    deleteArtcle() {...}
}
```

??

Comment: *Can* you? Sure--as long as Redux gets what it needs how that data is *created* doesn't matter (to Redux). The more important question is *should* it, to which there's no general answer. I'd be skeptical that a class is useful in most situations.

Comment: The big problem I've run into with storing classes in redux is serialization. When you retrieve from storage, the data will be POJO and without class. You will have to reconstruct the object if youre doing prototype checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume those functions are action creators? Ie, they return an object with a `type` property, and possibly some additional data?

```
function deleteArticle(id) {
  return { type: 'deleteArticles', id };
}
```

Or they may create thunks:

```
function deleteArticle(id) {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: 'deleteStarting' });
    // do something asynchronous
    dispatch({ type: 'deleteSuccessful' });
  }
}
```

If so, yes, you can put them in a class if you want. I don't see a benefit to putting these in a class, but redux doesn't even have a way to know how you created the actions, so it won't mind.